# Replace the list element of class

Tags: python, class

This is a homework to select a card from cards. After a card being selected, the card in list should be replaced by None.

```py
class Card():
   def __init__(self,cards):
       self._cards = cards

   def get_cards(self):
       return self._cards

   def get_card(self,slot):
       return self._cards[slot]
```

It is not allowed to change or add any other code for above class.

And the expected output shows below

```py
card1 = Card([1,2,3,4])
# card1.get_cards()=None (I try this but it does not work because it is not allowed to assign item to method)
print(card1.get_card(0)) # expectation: 1
print(card1.get_cards()) # expectation: [None, 2, 3, 4]
print(card1.get_card(1)) # expectation: 2
print(card1.get_cards()) # expectation: [None, None, 3, 4]
```

Comment: ok so method `get_cards` will return You an ref to list, just get this list and mutate it.

Comment: Why would a single card have information about the whole collection of cards? Did you perhaps mean to call this class `Deck` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a list in python, behind the scenes it is just a ref to this list.

So we can use this to our advantage here.

```
# You almost has done it right 
# take the list ref 
cards = card1.get_cards()
# and now mutate the list inside 
cards[slot] = None
```

The other solution is to monkey patch the `get_card` method, so the definition class itself won't be affected in the runtime we will attach new implementation to `get_card` method. If You need this second solution let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Card():
   def __init__(self,cards):
       self._cards = cards

   def get_cards(self):
       return self._cards

   def get_card(self,slot):
       return self._cards[slot]
```

Monkey patching the get_card function

```
def get_my_card(self, slot):
    card, self._cards[slot] = self._cards[slot], None
    return card
```

Time to test the above code

```
card1 = Card([1,2,3,4])
Card.get_card = get_my_card
print(card1.get_card(0)) # expectation: 1
print(card1.get_cards()) # expectation: [None, 2, 3, 4]
print(card1.get_card(1)) # expectation: 2
print(card1.get_cards()) # expectation: [None, None, 3, 4]
```

Output

```
1
[None, 2, 3, 4]
2
[None, None, 3, 4]
```

**Solution 2**: **Object-Oriented Approach**

```
class Card():    def __init__(self,cards):
        self._cards = cards

    def get_cards(self):
        return self._cards

    def get_card(self,slot):
        return self._cards[slot]
```

Create a derived class and overrride get_card method

```
class MyCard(Card):

    def get_card(self, slot):
        card, self._cards[slot] = self._cards[slot], None
        return card
```

Test the code

```
card1 = MyCard([1,2,3,4])
print(card1.get_card(0)) # expectation: 1
print(card1.get_cards()) # expectation: [None, 2, 3, 4]
print(card1.get_card(1)) # expectation: 2
print(card1.get_cards()) # expectation: [None, None, 3, 4]
```